# Odoo: ValueError: Invalid field 'user_id' in leaf

Tags: python, odoo

I am trying to create rule, to limit users to see only their records in tree view in my module, but it gives me error that 'user_id' field doesn't exist...

Heres my model:

```
class help_desk(models.Model):
    _name = 'help_desk.help_desk'

    name = fields.Char(string="Title", required=True)
    number = fields.Char(string="Mobile", required=True)
```

Here's the rule:

```
<record model="ir.rule" id="per_user_rule">
            <field name="name">User: see the individual Record</field>
            <field name="model_id" ref="model_help_desk_help_desk"/>
            <field name="domain_force">['|',('user_id','=',False),('user_id','=',user.id)]</field>
            <field name="groups" eval="[(4,ref('base.group_user'))]"/>
</record>
```

Here's the Error:

```
ValueError: Invalid field 'user_id' in leaf "<osv.ExtendedLeaf: ('user_id', '=', 9) on help_desk_help_desk (ctx: )>"
```

I am guessing, i have to add user_id field to my model, but how can i relate it to current user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution. I added the following field to my model:

```
user_id = fields.Many2one('res.users', string='User', track_visibility='onchange', readonly=True, 
                      states={'draft': [('readonly', False)]}, default=lambda self: self.env.user)
```

It takes the current user as default value.

Answer (score 1):

Change `user_id` to `create_uid`

`create_uid` - defines user  who created the record

```
<field name="domain_force">[('create_uid','=',uid)]</field>
```

Answer (score 0):

**.py file**
class help_desk(models.Model):
    _name = 'help_desk.help_desk'

```
name = fields.Char(string="Title", required=True)
number = fields.Char(string="Mobile", required=True)
user_id = fields.Many2one('res.users', string='User', track_visibility='onchange', readonly=True, states={'draft': [('readonly', False)]}, default=lambda self: self.env.user)
```

**security/.xml file** (**ir.rule**)

```
<record model="ir.rule" id="per_user_rule">
            <field name="name">User: see the individual Record</field>
            <field name="model_id" ref="model_help_desk_help_desk"/>
            <field name="domain_force">['|',('user_id','=',False),('user_id','=',user.id)]</field>
            <field name="groups" eval="[(4,ref('base.group_user'))]"/>
</record>
```